# Median value descriptive vs. quantile regression

Tags: r

I’m using quantile regression analysis to establish the median difference (and 95% confidence interval) between two observations.
Group 1 has an equal number of observations (X =0), group 2 (X =1) an unequal number.
Y = non-normally distributed continuous outcome.

A different median appears for X =0 using descriptive statistics vs quantile regression (in which the median of X = 0 should be the intercept).
It appears that descriptive statistics use the average of the two middle observations in case of an equal group number, whereas quantile regression takes the second observation.
This problem has been discussed amongst others in STATA as well (no solution) : https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1423807-qreg-vs-median-from-tabstat

Is there an alternative to quantreg that uses a different way to chose the median value (namely middle of two observations) or does anyone know how/where to alter the underlying quantreg script to adjust this?

I am aware that there are different ways to calculate medians, and none are right or wrong.

See below for script, depicting this problem. The two middle observations of Y in X =0 are 8 and 11.

```
install.packages("quantreg")
library(quantreg)
    

M <- matrix(ncol=2,nrow=3)
colnames(M) <- c('observed','quantreg')
rownames(M) <- c('X=0','X=1','diff')
   
 TAU = 0.5
    M[1,1] <- quantile(Y[X==0],TAU)
    M[2,1] <- quantile(Y[X==1],TAU)
    M[3,1] <- quantile(Y[X==1],TAU) - quantile(Y[X==0],TAU)
    fit <- rq(Y~X,tau=.5)
    M[1,2] <- as.numeric(fit$coef[1])
    M[3,2] <- fit$coef[2]
    M
    round(M,3)
```

This gives the following result:

|  | observed | quantreg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X = 0 | 9.5 | 11 |
| X = 1 | 44 | NA |
| Difference | 34.5 | 33 |

Comment: Bootstrapping might bring you closer to your desired result, but of course it is not without bias. `boot_coef <- boot.rq(x = cbind(1, X), y = Y, tau = 0.5, R = 1e5, method = "wild"); mean(boot_coef$B[,1]); mean(boot_coef$B[,2])`

Comment: Thank you for your time and comment. I have indeed tried bootstrapping, which yielded more similar results to the observed analysis from the descriptive statistics, but also influences amongst others the standard error. I was hoping to find a way to obtain the exact same results by adjusting the underlying method to 'pick' the median.